# Recursively print subfolder and subfolder in s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have s3 bucket `mybucket`, within which I have folder called `MyDocuments`. Within MyDocuments, I have three layers of folders, say `year, month, day`. Overall Hierarchy looks something like this:

```
mybucket
`-- MyDocuments
    `-- year=2021
        `-- month=01
            |-- day=10
            |   |-- file1
            |   `-- file2
            `-- day=20
                |-- file3
                `-- file4
        `-- month=02
            |-- day=30
            |   |-- file11
            |   `-- file21
            `-- day=20
                |-- file31
                `-- file41
```

Using boto3, I'd like to return following results containing subfolders in MyDocuments folder

```
year=2021/month=01/day=10
year=2021/month=01/day=20
year=2021/month=02/day=30
year=2021/month=02/day=20
```

What I've tried so far:

```
import boto3
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3client.list_objects(Bucket='mybucket', Prefix='MyDocuments', Delimiter="/")
sections = [x['Prefix'] for x in resp['CommonPrefixes']]
print(sections)
```

But this only gives me one level of subfolder:

```
['mybucket/MyDocuments/year=2021/']
```

I have millions of files within each day, how can I do this without pulling whole s3 files?

Comment: Do you need to retrieve files only on a given date prefix (i.e. all files inside `MyDocuments//year=2021/month=01/day=10`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think easier would be to use [s3 collection filters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/collections.html#boto3.resources.collection.ResourceCollection.filter):

```
import boto3

s3r = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3r.Bucket('mybucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='MyDocuments/').all():
  print(obj.key.rsplit('/', 1)[0])
```